Why do I keep getting an Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unauthenticated] UNAUTHENTICATED error when trying to execute HttpsCallable function
I keep getting the below error. I'm logged into my app as a user and use Firebase Authentication. The user account I'm logged in as is the only user and has Owner, Cloud Functions Admin, Cloud Functions Invoker, Cloud Run Admin, Cloud Run Invoker, and Firebase Admin roles. I don't think I need all these roles, I have just been trying anything I can to solve the authentication error.

CODE:
Future<void> helloWorldTest() async {
  HttpsCallable callableHW =
      FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
  final results = await callableHW.call();
  print('results are $results'); // Print the request data
}


const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const {onCall, HttpsError} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.helloWorld = onCall(async (request) => {
  return "Hello World";
});`


ERROR:

E/flutter (22286): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] >Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unauthenticated] >UNAUTHENTICATED

I tried to use HttpsCallable from my Flutter app to call an onCall >Firebase Cloud Function but keep getting the below error.

[firebase_functions/unauthenticated] UNAUTHENTICATED


The issue is likely because you need to initialize the Firebase Functions instance with your auth token. Here's how to fix it:


Future<void> helloWorldTest() async {
  // Get the current user
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  
  if (user != null) {
    // Get the ID token
    final idToken = await user.getIdToken();
    
    // Create the callable function with auth
    final callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance
        .httpsCallable('helloWorld');
    
    try {
      final result = await callable.call();
      print('Result: ${result.data}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }
}



Also make sure:

You've initialized Firebase properly in main.dart:



await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);




Your Firebase rules allow the function call

The user is actually authenticated before making the call



When I run that code, I still get the same error. However, I am able to print user and idToken and verify I am getting values there. The information for the user is correct and the token seems to be okay although I am not sure how to verify it is correct 100%.

To add to the above, I verified that I initialize Firebase in my main.dart. I am able to successfully read & write to my Cloud Firestore DB. My Firebase rules are pretty basic. The below applies to the entire database.
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  allow call: if request.auth != null;

I have read through the official Firebase documentation for "Call functions from your app". The only thing I don't cover is "Initializing the client SDK" for Firebase functions, but it doesn't list an option for Android so I assumed it wasn't applicable...
